# Set a props as part of href attribute in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have defined an icon component and I want the props to be attached to the href link address as part of the URL. How can this be done correctly?

In fact, I want the amount of attribute href to look like this:

`href="./img/icon.svg#ico_copy"`

```js
Vue.component('icon', {
  template: `
  <svg class="iconz">
  <use v-bind:href="'./img/icon.svg#'+ props.label"></use>
  </svg>`,
  props: {
    label: String,
  },
});
```

```html
  <icon label="ico_copy"></icon>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a computed property like this:

```
computed: {
  url() {
    return `./img/icon.svg#${this.label}`;
  }
}
```